# bootstrap align nav li with navbar-brand

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to get the nav bar link to align centrally with the nav brand

here is my code so far

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pivwh

for some reason the contact is lower and I can't get the links to align to the right.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
.nav {
  float:right;
}

.nav li a{
  line-height: 99px;
}

.nav li {
  font-size: 24px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FtyCg

Comment: Check my updated answer, I think line-height is better to use than margin when you want to center the nav vertically to the logo. @user2942720

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
.navbar-nav {
  margin-top: 60px;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GAhwz

Comment: Thanks thats great how would you get it to align the links to the right?